# why isn't the following code not printing out prime numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so I've been trying to print prime numbers on the screen and I just couldn't make it work it just prints out all the numbers in the range.

```
 public static void Main()
{
   
        bool isPrime = false;
        for (int i = 2; i < 100; i ++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
                else
                    isPrime = true;
            }
            if (isPrime)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which will help you write better code.

Comment: When you know it is not prime you need to stop testing right away!!

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for a very long time that's why I posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it and commented where your errors are.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < 100; i ++) {
            bool isPrime = false; // Doesn't reset when loop starts
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break; // Should break out of loop to check otherwise constantly true
                }
                else { // No brackets around the else
                    isPrime = true; 
                }
            }
            if (isPrime)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lottt, but is the "i ! = j " necessary since I specified that j is less than i?

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten that to:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
{
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j < i && isPrime; j++)
    {
        isPrime = (i % j != 0);
    }
    if (isPrime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

It could shortened even more, but I think it's not as readable:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
{
    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j < i && isPrime; isPrime = (i % j != 0), j++) { }
    if (isPrime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```